# Get input values using Selenium in Python outputs None

Tags: python, html, selenium

**My Item:**

```
<input id="a0" class="someclassname" size="55" placeholder="empty" value="scarping-test">
```

**My Code:**

```
items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='a0']")
for item in items:
    href = item.get_attribute('href')
    print(href)
```

**Output:**

> None

**Expected:**

> scarping-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That input doesn't have an `href` attribute. The attribute you're looking for is called `value`.

So what you are looking for is:

```
item = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='a0']").get_attribute('value')
```

I used `find_element()` instead of `find_elements()` since it has no sense to find for more than one element and loop through the list; the element with `id='a0'` can only be one (id is a unique identifier).

Comment: thx a lot! I was blind!

Comment: It happens to everyone, don't worry ;)

Answer (score 1):

The attribute here is `value`, not `href`.
So, instead of

```py
href = item.get_attribute('href')
```

Try

```py
value = item.get_attribute('value')
```

So, the entire code will be:

```py
items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='a0']")
for item in items:
    value = item.get_attribute('value')
    print(value)
```

Comment: This is what code review is required...